# JavaScript traverse Json array and select different attribute to save but get same array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not good at JavaScript and I meet a problem and It bothers me a lot.Hope someone can help me.
Here is the JS code:

```
<script>
var data = [
    {"":"AT1G61780","baseMean":"849.058775137712","log2FoldChange":"-8.90368140154262","lfcSE":"0.466042198257675","stat":"-19.104882422299","pvalue":2.29944969924087e-81,"padj":5.06798713712688e-77},
    {"":"AT5G37130","baseMean":"4294.59961310424","log2FoldChange":"3.27327875544505","lfcSE":"0.182729052190661","stat":"17.9132913797949","pvalue":9.28774588475587e-72,"padj":1.0235095965001e-67},
    {"":"AT2G22330","baseMean":"1462.21154035855","log2FoldChange":"-2.04203848172526","lfcSE":"0.19028685011923","stat":"-10.7313694059561","pvalue":7.25135115276992e-27,"padj":5.32732598023497e-23},
    {"":"AT4G39950","baseMean":"1767.03303498768","log2FoldChange":"-1.71531773333609","lfcSE":"0.18987118053785","stat":"-9.03411317334783","pvalue":1.65337563321386e-19,"padj":9.11009973900836e-16},
    {"":"AT4G07850.1","baseMean":"157.215533895214","log2FoldChange":"-3.41991052916375","lfcSE":"0.384125650856733","stat":"-8.90310376705167","pvalue":5.43063674541315e-19,"padj":2.39382467737812e-15},
    {"":"AT4G33467","baseMean":"164.107317842216","log2FoldChange":"-3.88623993122809","lfcSE":"0.469140396775025","stat":"-8.28374609806141","pvalue":1.19359945117813e-16,"padj":4.38448865066102e-13}];

var sbt = log2FC = pp = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      sbt.push(data[i][""]);
      log2FC.push(data[i]["log2FoldChange"]);
      pp.push(data[i]["padj"]);
    };

console.log(sbt);
console.log(log2FC);
console.log(pp);
</script>
```

I want to use JS to traverse JSON data to respective save each member object three value(object[""],object["log2FoldChange"],object["padj"]) to three different array.But finally I console.log the result to find the three array are totally same like the picture show.I don't know why.Thanks Advance!!!
[image]

Comment: You've assigned all three arrays to point to the same reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you declare data like:

```
var sbt = log2FC = pp = [];
```

It actually means:

```
pp = [];
log2FC = pp;
var sbt = log2FC
```

So, you are basically assigning same empty array as a reference to all the three variables. So, data pushed in any array `pp`, `log2FC` or `sbt` is actually pushed to all three of them, thus you are getting the issue.

You can resolve it by declaring variables like:

```
var sbt = [], log2FC = [], pp = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your arrays like this instead:

```js
var sbt = [];
var log2FC = [];
var pp = [];
```

Otherwise you're just assigning them all to each other